# Standard SQL consistently slower than Legacy SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

We noticed that queries executed with standard `SQL` are usually a bit slower and many times by a factor 5. The following query that gets the count of hits is done in 1.8s with legacy `SQL`, but takes 10s using standard `SQL`. The queries are:

**Legacy SQL:**

```
SELECT
  max_time,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT
    MAX(hits.time) WITHIN RECORD AS max_time,
  FROM
    [google_analytics.ga_sessions_20160601])
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

**Standard SQL:**

```
SELECT
  (SELECT MAX(time) FROM sessions.hits) AS max_time,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
  `google_analytics.ga_sessions_20160601` AS sessions
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

We notice that the amount of "compute" in the first stage is usually a bit higher and there's more wait in the final stage.

Other queries like a simple `SELECT COUNT(*)` also have similar differences.

Is it true that standard `SQL` is consistently slower than legacy `SQL`?

Comment: I am still observing this to be the case (Jan 2017).

Comment: I'm observing (May 2017) the same issue: std SQL is 2-3x slower. Example is `SELECT substr(title,1,1) t, count(1) cnt, sum(id), sum(num_characters)
FROM [bigquery-public-data.samples.wikipedia]
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY cnt desc` which takes under 4,5s in legacy and over 9s in standard SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report - we will investigate it. Standard SQL is still in Beta, and there is some known performance work that needs to be done before final release - we will check whether it affects your queries as well.

Comment: This is still happening as of March 2017 with most queries around 2-3x slower with standard sql.

Comment: @ManiGandham - can you provide job ids for fast (legacy) and slow (standard) queries - we do not have such discrepancy in our tests, but perhaps it depends on your data ?

Comment: GCP support case #12209159 confirms this with staff. instinctive-01:bquijob_1c21511b_15a8bda9ad0 for legacy.
instinctive-01:bquijob_1e7d55a5_15a8bda7329 for standard.

Comment: @ManiGandham - thanks - I checked these queries, the absolute difference between them is about 1 second - 1.2 seconds vs. 2.5 seconds, so while it is technically 2x times, this doesn't translate to 2x when input data volume grows.

Comment: Why is there a difference at all with parsing the SQL itself if the underlying query is the same? Just ran similar query on 646GB github_repos.commits table with same results, standard takes about 2-3x as long as legacy. This has also been confirmed by the support team in my open case. There is *definitely* a performance issue with the new standard sql format.

Comment: It will help if you can provide the actual query or job ids. With performance every case is different.

Comment: Can you check this support case? #12209159 They mentioned you so easier to talk on that thread.

Comment: Ack - will follow up on support case.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky I'm observing same issue: std SQL is 2-3x slower. Example is `SELECT substr(title,1,1) t, count(1) cnt, sum(id), sum(num_characters)
FROM [bigquery-public-data.samples.wikipedia]
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY cnt desc` which takes under 4,5s in legacy and over 9s in standard SQL. But with my own data slowdown is even 10x.

Comment: This is still happening and is rather pronounced on tiny datasets where I have 1.3 seconds for Legacy SQL but 5 seconds for Standard SQL. The JobID for Legacy SQL is calcium-verbena-170009:bquijob_5e4e1255_15cab03d570 and the JobID for Standard SQL is calcium-verbena-170009:bquijob_46c1e054_15cab038192

Comment: @Twist - thank you for this report, and for attaching job ids. I confirm the problem. This is a performance bug, ironically it happens when input and output are tiny (few thousands rows). Please file this specific report as a bug under https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149 so you can track our progress in fixing it.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky Thank you very much for confirming this. I have logged it as per your suggestion.